# Why i am not able to deep copy a class member

Tags: c++, c++11

Not able to deep copy one class object to another;

I have a geometry Class object

```
class Geometry
 {
  public:   
     std::string stdstrType;
     bool bValid;

 public:

  Geometry()
    {
       stdstrType = "NO_TYPE";
       bValid = false;

    }

  Geometry( std::string strType , bool bValue )
  {
    stdstrType = strType;
    bValid = bValue;        
  }

 Geometry(const Geometry &g)
{
    stdstrType = g.stdstrType;
    bValid = g.bValid;
}

 ~Geometry()
 {
     qDebug() << "Geometry  destructor called";
 } 

 virtual void draw();
 bool isValid();
 void setValidState(bool bState);
 virtual void Init();
 std::string GetName(); 
};
```

I have a Container class

```
 class Container
  {
   private:
    std::string stdstrContainerName;
    std::string stdstrPluginType;
    Geometry* Geom;

  public:
    Container();
    Container(std::string, std::string, Geometry* geometry = nullptr);
    Container(const  Container& obj);
    ~Container();
    std::string GetName();
    std::string GetType();
    void SetName(std::string stdstrName);
    Geometry* GetGeometry();
    void SetGeometry(Geometry* Geom);

  };



 Container::Container(std::string strName, std::string strType, Geometry* 
 geometry) : Geom(geometry)
{
   stdstrContainerName = strName;
  stdstrPluginType = strType;   
}


 Container::Container(const Container& obj) {
  stdstrContainerName = obj.stdstrContainerName;
  stdstrPluginType = obj.stdstrPluginType;
  Geom = new Geometry;
  *Geom = *obj.Geom;  // This Line gives error
 }
```

since Container object has a data member with Geometry pointer and the scope of geometry object is shorter than the container object 
so i want to do a deep copy geometry object inside the Container object.

This is the line in copy constructor which gives me error

```
*Geom = *obj.Geom;  // This Line gives error
```

This is how i Initilize the Container object

```
 Geometry* geom = new Geometry;
 Container* cont = new Container("Group", "NONE", geom);
```

Comment: try Geom = new Geometry(obj.Geom)

Comment: Hi Capibar i get this error Geometry::Geometry(const Geometry &)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'Geometry *const ' to 'const Geometry &

Comment: What is wrong with this `*Geom = *obj.Geom;  // This Line gives error` what kind of error are you getting ?

Comment: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000020.

Comment: Before copying you should test `if (obj.Geom )` to check if a container has a valid geometry, your Container constructors allow `geom` to be `nullptr`, so what happens in `Container cont1("group","NONE");  Container cont2(cont1);` ? copy constructors of `Container` access `geom` pointer which is null.

Comment: Thanks rafix i understood your point can you please let me know how i can fix this.

Comment: also  Container::Container(std::string strName, std::string strType, Geometry* 
 geometry) defined twice

Comment: apologies that is a error in copy pasting the code , it is only defined once in the project.

Comment: Note that, since C++11: _The generation of the implicitly-defined copy assignment operator is deprecated if `T` has a user-declared destructor or user-declared copy constructor._. This is the case of your `Geometry` class.

Comment: Thanks daniel how can i make it work.

Comment: Have you thought about overloading assignment operator (= operator) for your `Geometry` class?

Comment: Cannot reproduce: https://wandbox.org/permlink/fyOa5UI5YZK7xEtl. I am afraid that the problem is in some code we don't see. Please, create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). There is no copy constructor involved in the code you show us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented by @rafix07, you should always check pointer before dereferencing it.

```
if(obj.Geom != nullptr) // Check
  *Geom = *obj.Geom;
```

Also along with copy constructor, you should consider defining assignment operator for `Geometry` class, to achieve your objective of deep copy.

```
Geometry & Geometry::operator = (const Geometry &g)
{  
  if(this != &g)
  {
    stdstrType = g.stdstrType;
    bValid = g.bValid;
  } 
  return *this;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

The generation of the implicitly-defined copy assignment operator is deprecated if T has a user-declared destructor or user-declared copy constructor.

You need to define an assignment operator for your class

```
Geometry& operator = (const Geometry &g)
Container& operator = (const Container& c)
```

Comment: Being deprecated doesn't mean that it won't work. I don't think this is an answer to the question. That's what comments are for.